# Get DOM element using meteor template helpers

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, handlebars.js

For example my html is

```
<template name="atest">
 <a href="{{route}}" data-test="test">Click</a>
</template>
```

In meteor template helpers, I want to be able to select the anchor tag.

```
Template.atest.route = function() {
 console.log(this.data-test);
};
```

I am not sure if this can be done or not, but certainly, it cannot be done via any method I have tried. I know there is a way to pass argument in a template instance, but I don't want that. I want to be able to select that anchor tag that template instance is in and do something with it.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not in helpers, but in the `rendered` callback you can do:

```
Template.atest.rendered = function() {
  var el = this.find("[data-test]");
};
```

And in event handlers:

```
Template.atest.events({
  "click a": function( event, template ) {
    var selectEl = template.find("[data-test]"); // Arbitrary element in template
    var targetEl = event.target;                 // Element that triggered the event
    var currentEl = event.currentTarget;         // Element that is handling this event function (the element referenced by "click a")
  }
});
```

Of course, you could also do:

```
Template.atest.events({
  "click a[data-test]": function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

If none of these options work for you, you might want to reevaluate your approach. Needing access to an element from a helper function indicates that you are trying to use a procedural coding style rather than a template-driven style. In general, don't store data on DOM nodes, store it in the template's context object.

Could you give some additional context on what exactly you're trying to do? There might be a better way.

Think about this: the helper has to be called in order to render the element. How would you be able to access the element if it doesn't even exist yet?

Edit: here is a template-driven approach to attaching `href` attributes to a template depending on where it is defined. Basically, you want to include the necessary data to generate the link template in any associated parent template. Then, just call the link template with that data:

HTML:

```
<body>
  {{> parent1}}
</body>

<template name="parent1">
  <div>
    {{> link linkData}}
  </div>

  <ul>
    {{#each arrayData}}
      <li>{{> link}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  {{#with arbitraryData}}
    {{> parent2}}
  {{/with}}

</template>

<template name="parent2">
  <p>{{> link transformedData}}</p>
</template>

<template name="link">
  <a href="{{href}}">{{text}}</a>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.parent1.linkData = {
    href: "/path/to/something",
    text: "Parent Template 1 Link"
  };

  Template.parent1.arrayData = [
    { href: "array/path/1", text: "Array path one" },
    { href: "array/path/2", text: "Array path two" }
  ];

  Template.parent1.arbitraryData = {
    link: "/foo/bar/baz",
    name: "Parent Template 2 Link"
  };

  Template.parent2.transformedData = function() {
    return { href: this.link, text: this.name };
  };
}
```

Comment: Basically the same template are being generated couple of times in the DOM.
Now I am trying to attach href properties to the anchor tag based to its position in the dom.

But you are probably right, it might be better to go with events click or hover route.

Right now I am also trying Deps.autorun with jquery and that seems to be working fine too.

Comment: @Bads See my edit. I know in your OP you say that you don't want to pass a data argument to your link template. Is there any reason why? As you can see in my edit, this approach is very flexible and is truly the Meteor way to do it. In the `#each` block you don't even need to use an argument. Zero jQuery needed.

Comment: @Bads also note that if you only use jQuery inside your `Deps.autorun`, the function isn't actually going to be re-run, and might not affect your templates as they change. You need to drive the autorun function with a reactive data source. If you're implementing a reactive data source to do DOM manipulation in autorun functions as your data changes, you're really getting into an impedance mismatch between procedural and template-driven programming. The point of Meteor's template engine is that it does all this stuff for you.

Comment: OMG! You completely solved it...I was trying to come up with something like this for days. Thanks!!

The reason I didn't want to pass the data because the same data would be passed no matter where it is generated in the DOM, and I didn't know how that would help.