# Showing an alert box as a response to a Meteor error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Basically I have something like the following in my Meteor app. There is a plus sign on a page that should trigger an `add` operation when clicked. If the `add` operation fails for some reason, I would like to show an alert box in the html to the user.

In "normal" procedural programming with jQuery this would mean finding the right element and attach the html with the alert to that node. That is not a very good fit for the reactive model in Meteor, and so I am at a loss on what to do.

The problem is to understand how I can set the values needed for the template to render. This is my code so far, which simply does not work.

**HTML**

```
<template name="wish">
<div data-wish-id={{_id}} class="count items-bought">                        
    <a href="#" class="plus-sign"></a>
    <a href="#" class="minus-sign"></a>
</div>

{{#if alertMessage}}
{{> alert}}
{{/if}}
</template>

<template name="alert">
<div class="alert alert-{{alertLevel}} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span
            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    {{alertMessage}}
</div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.wish.events({
    'click .plus-sign' : function(e, template) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var parent = $(e.target).parent();
        var id = parent.data('wish-id');

        buy(id, function(err) {
            if(err) { set_values_alertMessage_and_alertLevel_on_right_scope(); }
        });

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing I am in the same boat as this guy, but I am not sure how to relate to the answer given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780843/get-dom-element-using-meteor-template-helpers

Comment: Do you mean to set a 'click .glyphicon-plus-sign' event?

Comment: Also, you can simply do `var id = template.data._id;` and avoid the need to store the `_id` value as a `data-*` attribute on your div.

Comment: 1. You're right. I changed the name and forgot to update the code both places. Good catch.
2. So you mean to say the data context that is being used to fill the drawn template with values is accessible on the `data` field? Nice to know. I guess it won't make much sense to add the error message back onto the data context object as that is lost as soon as the backing data changes or a redraw is made.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) to control application state.

When your app starts, set the default session value:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Session.setDefault("alertMessage", null);
});
```

Then listen for it in your template:

```
Template.wish.alertMessage = function() {
  return !Session.equals("alertMessage", null);
}
```

And set it when you need to:

```
buy(id, function(err) {
  if (err) Session.set("alertMessage", err.message);
});
```

Then draw it:

```
Template.alert.alertMessage = function() {
  return Session.get("alertMessage");
}
```

Comment: I see no reason having `Session.setDefault("showAlert", null)` in the startup callback. Am I missing something?

Comment: I always declare the default Session values during startup for clarity, as a good convention. It's not necessary, but I recommend doing it anyway.

Comment: I thought about doing that myself, but I don't think that would work. The reason being that there are multiple rendered templates. All of them would then show the same error message! I need the error message to be specific to that single instance of the template. The other templates could have other alerts (not necessarily errors) popping up for other reasons.

Comment: That sounds like a confusing user experience. If I click "buy" on an item in my wish list, wouldn't I want a single alert to give me feedback if the process throws an error? Rather than seeing multiple messages per instance of me doing something?

Comment: I can edit the wording to be something else, bu my problem ATM is technical, not ux :)

Comment: What about setting id-prefixed Session attributes? I could have a helper, Template.wish.alertMessage(), that checked for `Session.get(this._id + "_alertMessage")` and returned that if defined, else null. That would work right?